# How can I create a setup file to add to the Windows Store?

Tags: c#, winforms, certificate, windows-store-apps, setup-project

I have a Win Form(.net 4.7.2) project developed with C#. I right click on my project in Visual Studo and use the Publish menu to create setup files. I have a code signing certificate for my project that I renew every year.I get an error when I want to add my app to the Windows Store.

`App Policies: 10.2.9

Win32 products must be submitted as a standalone/offline installer. Installers must not be a downloader that downloads the bits it needs to run. Please resubmit with an appropriate installer.`

For more details for App Policies: 10.2.9: https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/windows/uwp/publish/store-policies

Do I need to create a setup project in Visual Studio? I didn't understand exactly what to do. How can I research this?

When I Publish the project, the installation file and many folders are created. I know this is not a professional setup file, but I need a solid, secure setup file signed with certificates. I couldn't figure out how to do this, I don't even know how to search.

Comment: Is your setup file an exe file or msi file? You must enter at least one versioned secure URL pointing to app package (MSI/EXE) hosted on your CDN when you are trying to add a package URL in the package page.

Comment: Hey Roy, thank you for your answer.

My entire website works with https and the downloaded link is https.

Actually, the file extension after publishing is .exe and .application. 

However, I created a setup project in my project because the Windows store wanted a setup file. I added the resulting .exe and .msi file to the windows store.

Comment: Have you checked if you could download your app correctly from the URL you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to distribute a C# (WinForms/WPF) application in Microsoft Store would be to package the app into an Appx package using Visual Studio. I uploaded my WPF application to MS Store by the following procedure:

1. Add a Windows Application Packaging Project to my solution in Visual Studio
2. Right click Dependencies of the Packaging project -> Add Project Reference to my application project
3. Right click the Packaging project -> Publish -> Create App Packages

Comment: Hey @kmaki565, thanks it is work for me. 

But it created me a setup file with 6 files and 2 folders. Microsoft Store is asking for just exe or msi  a setup file. Can I use these files in Microsoft Store?

[link](https://ibb.co/nstJ1NT)

Comment: Hi @FarukDurak, in my case (with VS2022) .msixbundle is created (not .appxbundle) and that is the one I upload to Microsoft Partner Center. You could try uploading the .appxbundle.

Comment: Hey @kmaki565,I was able to make the .appxbundle file by creating a new project and choosing the type PWA. However, the installation file downloaded from the website is an exe file and in this case I need to make them .appxbundle.

I get security warnings by windows smartscreen during installation, I would have solved those as well.

And when I check other installation files, they all use files with exe or msi extension. There must be a reason for this, I have never downloaded and installed an application with the .appxbundle extension, do people have trust problems?